# Style is not found

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I have a WPF application with Caliburn.Micro. I have a style defined in ResourceDictionary/Styles.xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="DisplayNameTextBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF414462" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4,4,4,0" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13.333" />
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>
```

I am trying to apply it to my control like this:

```
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <telerik:RadBusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}">
        <StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot">
            <StackPanel Margin="0 0 0 0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Style="{StaticResource DisplayNameTextBlockStyle}"
                           Text="Data Entry" />
```

But because of some reason, on loading this view I am getting an exception:

Cannot find resource named 'DisplayNameTextBlockStyle'. Resource names are case sensitive."

Could you please help? Thanks.

Comment: How/where are you including `Styles.Xaml` in your resources at runtime?

Comment: Could you please explain what including in resources at runtime means? Sorry for my naivety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically this happens because your resource dictionary hasn't been loaded.  You can manage this in many ways; the simplest is to include the following in your `app.xaml` file:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionary/styles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```